# File upload to S3 via PowerShell not working (Used to work)

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sql-job

For the past couple years we've had an automated SQL Job that ran some PowerShell scripts to move out DB backups to S3 and other AWS services.

Recently these stopped working.  I've been hitting my head against this without any luck.

Our job has multiple steps:

**Step 1**

Backup Databases to Backup drive

**Step 2**

```
Set-AWSCredentials -AccessKey = $$$$$$$$$ -SecretKey = $$$$$$$$$ -StoreAs default
```

**Step 3** (used for each Database)

```
$dir = "z:\Database_Backup\X"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$full_name = $dir + "\" + $latest.name 
$target_s3_dir = "s3://X-X-backup/"

$today_dd = GET-DATE -UFORMAT "%d"
if($today_dd -eq "01") {
    $target_name = $target_s3_dir + "X_"  + (GET-DATE -UFORMAT "%Y_%m_%d") + ".Bak"
}  else {
    $target_name =  $target_s3_dir + "X_" +  (GET-DATE).DayOfWeek + ".Bak"
}

aws s3 cp $full_name  $target_name

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | ?{-not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit} | Remove-Item
```

The errors I'm getting from the SQL Job are as follows:

> The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not
>   stop the script:  A job step received an error at line 17 in a
>   PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'aws s3 cp $full_name 
>   $target_name  '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error
>   information returned by PowerShell is: 'upload failed:
>   z:\Database_Backup\X\X_FullDB_2018.02.06_07.00.00.Bak to
>   s3://x-x-backup/X_Tuesday.Bak Unable to locate credentials  '. 
>   Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

**What I've Tried**

I gave our AIM user the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::x-x-backup"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::x-x-backup/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using this command instead of  aws s3 cp:

```
 Write-S3Object -BucketName $s3Bucket -File $full_name -Key $latest.name -Region $region -AccessKey $accessKey -SecretKey $secretKey
```

but that gave me the error:

> The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.  The
>   remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.  The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.  '.

**Update**

I've updated the credentials in [Users].aws\credentials with the access and security key, and it is returning the same errors.

Any thoughts on how to get this working?  IT stopped working the day one of our drives ran out of space, and hasn't worked since. Weird I know, but that's where I am .

Comment: The command line options for Set-AWSCredentials are specified as -AccessKey xxx, not as -AccessKey=xxx. Similarly for the secret key.

Comment: If you have setup your credentials correctly (stored on the file system) then you will not have to specify credentials on the command line.

Comment: I've modified the script for Set-AWSCredentials, as well as updated the credentials in \Users\Administrator\.aws\credentials and it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Not really. I found a work around within SQL Server, but it isn't a pure solution, but i needed my backups to work. :\